# HTTP service get/shows wrong value

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, httpservice

I'm populating an advanceddatagrid through a http service call. I define a HTTPService in my mxml file like this:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="srvReadMicroData"/>
```

It receives this simple "XML file" ...

```
<MicroDataSet>
  <Row arb_id='982215013000269378' />
</MicroDataSet>
```

... through these functions:

```
public function readMicroData():void
{
  ...
  srvReadMicroData.url = myUrl;
  srvReadMicroData.method = "POST";
  srvReadMicroData.addEventListener("result", httpReadMicroDataResult);
  srvReadMicroData.send();
}

public function httpReadMicroDataResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
  myGrid.dataProvider=srvReadMicroData.lastResult.MicroDataSet.Row;
  myGrid.validateNow();
}
```

When I run debug in Flashbuilder and look at the value of the http service, the last three digits is different. The value changes again when I do a toString(). It seems to happen with large numbers:

> srvReadMicroData.lastResult.IseeMicroDataSet.Row["arb_id"]  -->
>   982215013000269440
>   srvReadMicroData.lastResult.IseeMicroDataSet.Row["arb_id"].toString()
>   --> 982215013000269300

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the value you're trying to get is larger than Flex maximum one, so it rounds it.
You could add a "A" letter at the begin of your 'arb_id' string in this way:

```
<MicroDataSet>
    <Row arb_id='a982215013000269378' />
</MicroDataSet>
```

In this way, flex gets the 'arb_id' object as a String. Then you can substring it removeing the 'a' character.
Finally you will have a string representing exactly the value in your xml.

Hope to have been helpful

Answer (score 0):

If **srvReadMicroData.lastResult** contains **XML** data, then you can process as below:

```
private var _xml:XML;
[Bindable]
private var rowArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
public function httpReadMicroDataResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
    _xml = XML(srvReadMicroData.lastResult);
    for each (var row:XML in _xml.Row) {
        var rowObject:Object = new Object();
        rowObject.arb_id = row.attribute("arb_id");
        //trace("rowID: " + rowObject.arb_id);
        rowArrayCollection.addItem(rowObject);
    }
    myGrid.dataProvider = rowArrayCollection;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working with my data. However, it is possible for me to change the file format. How should it look like?

Comment: You may want to go through these: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdd.html http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/accessingdata/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdc.html